# Transition on line chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, transition

In my line chart, initially all data needed for plot line. There is two button `Make` and `sell`, If I click on any one of the button, data related to that button should be plotted for line with transition effect as shown in [this link](http://dataaddict.fr/prenoms/#aldo) . I have tried to make this work, but I can't. I tried to make relation between button and line chart as given below(code), its not working. I have hard coded `buttonId` in my code with `sell` to have data related to `sell`, if I change it to `Make` I will get data related to `Make` but I need to hard coded here. what I want is when a `Make` button clicked data related to `Make` should come with transition as above link shown. My code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.chart.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="vis"></div>
<button id="Make">Make</button>
<button id="sell">sell</button>
<script type="text/javascript">


d3.chart("linechart", {

  initialize: function() {
    // create a base scale we will use later.
   var chart = this;
    chart.w = chart.base.attr('width') || 200;
    chart.h = chart.base.attr('height') || 150;
    chart.w = +chart.w;
    chart.h = +chart.h;
    buttonId = 'sell'
   chart.x = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([0, chart.w]);

  chart.y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([chart.h,0]);

  chart.base.classed('line', true);

  this.areas = {};
      chart.areas.lines = chart.base.append('g')
              .classed('lines', true)
              .attr('width', chart.w)
              .attr('height', chart.h)

       chart.line = d3.svg.line()
                  .x(function(d) { return chart.x(d.x);})   
                  .y(function(d) { return chart.y(d.y);});


    this.layer("lines", chart.areas.lines, {
dataBind: function(data) {
    // update the domain of the xScale since it depends on the data
       chart.y.domain([d3.min(data,function(d){return d.y}),d3.max(data,function(d){return d.y})])
 var mydata=new Array();
if(buttonId)
{
  var j=0;
  for(var i in data)
  {
   if(data[i].custody === buttonId){mydata[j] = data[i]; j++;};
  }
  chart.x.domain(d3.extent(mydata, function(d) { return d.x; }));
}
else
{
  chart.x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; }));
}

    // return a data bound selection for the passed in data.
    return this.selectAll("path").data([data]);
  },
 insert: function() {
    return this.append("path")
              .datum(data)
              .attr("d", chart.line)
              .attr('stroke','#1ABC9C')
              .attr('stroke-width','2')
              .attr('fill','none');

  }

    });
  },

  // configures the width of the chart.
  // when called without arguments, returns the
  // current width.
  width: function(newWidth) {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
      return this.w;
    }
    this.w = newWidth;
    return this;
  },

  // configures the height of the chart.
  // when called without arguments, returns the
  // current height.
  height: function(newHeight) {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
      return this.h;
    }
    this.h = newHeight;
    return this;
  },

});

var data = [
{x: 0,y:190, custody: "Make"},
  {x: 1,y:10, custody: "Make"},{x: 2,y:40, custody: "Make"},{x: 3,y:90, custody: "Make"},
  {x: 4,y:30, custody: "sell"},{x: 5,y:20, custody: "sell"},{x: 6,y:10, custody: "sell"},
  {x: 7,y:40, custody: "sell"}
];

var chart1 = d3.select("#vis")
  .append("svg")
  .chart("linechart")
  .width(720)
  .height(320)

chart1.draw(data);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Get `d3.chart.min.js` from [d3.chart.min.js](https://github.com/misoproject/d3.chart)
and get `d3.v3.min.js` from [d3.v3.min.js](http://d3js.org/)

Comment: it would be easier to use d3 to select the button, apply a .on("change", function (d) { //stuff that happens when button is pressed }) to make the line update to the press of the button, a link with the explanation can be seen here: http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/update-d3js-data-dynamically-button.html

Comment: Since you're using the d3.chart framework, read their information on how to handle updating data (what they call "lifecycle events"): https://github.com/misoproject/d3.chart/wiki/lifecycle-events.  If that's enough for you to figure it out, come back and answer your own question; if not, come back and edit the question to indicate what you've tried and what is still confusing you.